# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'iid'

Tags: python, data-science, svm, bayessearchcv

I found best parameters and best score using ***GridSearchCV*** and ***RandomizedSearchCV*** for my TCSVM model.
and now i want to use the ***BayesSearchCV*** in order to compare it with previous methods, but i got this error `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'iid'`

this is my code that i used:

```
    model2 = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), SVC())
    parameter_grid = {
            'C': Real(1e-5, 1e+3, prior='log-uniform'),
            'gamma': Real(2e-2, 2e+3, prior='log-uniform'),
            'degree': Integer(1, 8),
            'kernel': Categorical(['linear', 'poly', 'rbf']),
        }
    grid_searchdt = BayesSearchCV(estimator=model2, search_spaces=parameter_grid, n_iter=32, cv=5, random_state=0,
                                  iid=True)
    grid_searchdt.fit(X_Train, Y_Train)
    grid_searchdt.score(X_Test, Y_Test)
    print("Score opt =", grid_searchdt.score(X_Test, Y_Test))
    print("Best_Params =", grid_searchdt.best_params_)
    print("Best_Score =", grid_searchdt.best_score_)
```

i read some solution that said i need to downgrade scikit-learn version but it didn't works for me.
any solution please.

Comment: first read documentation for `BayesSearchCV` because it seems it can't get `iid` - so remove it or check in documentation can get it with different name

Comment: yes it can't get `iid` as a parameter `BayesSearchCV ` definition, but when i run my code it gaves me the same error, also i putted `iid = False` also same error

Comment: you have to remove `iid=` - don't use it.

Comment: @furas the idd parameter does appear in the docs. A traceback might help. Plus a reproducible example or at least the import lines.

Comment: based on documentation - the newest version [0.9 (dev)](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/dev/modules/generated/skopt.BayesSearchCV.html#skopt.BayesSearchCV) doesn't uses `iid` but [0.8.1](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/modules/generated/skopt.BayesSearchCV.html) still have it. If you really need `iid` then you have to downgrade it. If it doesn't work then you didn't downgrade it correctly. Or you have to Python installed and you downgraded it in one Python but you run code with different Python.

Comment: if you run code `python3.8 script.py` then you could install it with `python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade scikit-optimize==0.8.1` And later check version `import skopt` `print(skopt.__version__)`

Comment: @furas i got the same error

Comment: did you check `print(skopt.__version__)` directly before `BayesSearchCV` ? Maybe you have two Pythons installed and you installed `0.8.1` in one Python but you run code in second Python which still have `0.9`

Comment: yes when i try to use this command `python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade scikit-optimize==0.8.1`, i got this:  `Requirement already satisfied: scikit-optimize==0.8.1 in c:\users\youssef.dougmi\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (0.8.1)`, that means i have been installed the 0.8.1 version

Comment: @furas, Finally it works, i uninstall scikit-learn using `pip uninstall scikit-learn`, and install it again, after that i installed  scikit-optimize  using  `pip install --upgrade scikit-optimize==0.23.3`  so after that when i run my code it works pretty fine

Answer (score 1):

Finally it works, i uninstall scikit-learn using `pip uninstall scikit-learn`, and install it again, after that i installed scikit-optimize using `pip install --upgrade scikit-optimize==0.23.3` so after that when i run my code it works pretty fine.

thank you @furas for your help

Comment: I try your solution but it raises an error: `ERROR: No matching distribution found for scikit-optimize==0.23.3`. Could u help please?